# How to center a flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I want ABCD on the left and DATE should be in the center. How to achieve this?

```css
.flex-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-left: 17px;
}

.abcd1 {}

.date1 {
  /*this item should be in the center.*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-items">
  <div class="abcd1">ABCD</div>
  <div class="date1">DATE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin:auto on date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```css
.flex-items {

  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-left: 17px;
}

.abcd1 {

}

.date1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-items">

<div class="abcd1">ABCD</div>
<div class="date1">DATE</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Great, done thanks :)

Comment: text-align is useless here

Comment: yes, we can remove text-align here.

Comment: Yes i have removed it.

Comment: This solution doesn't center the DATE on the full line. It centers the DATE only in the *remaining space* of the line. DATE is off-center (to the right) by the length of the ABCD element. https://jsfiddle.net/5wm9e0d0/1

Answer (score 0):

See below. Hope this helps.

```css
.flex-items {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 17px;
  text-align: center;
}

.date1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-items">
  <div class="abcd1">ABCD</div>
  <div class="date1">DATE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin-right is useless here

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif. Code adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Text-align: center works when there is a width provided.
This also works:

```css
.flex-items {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-start;
     padding-left: 17px;
}
.abcd1 {
          
}     
.date1 {
     /*this item should be in the center.*/
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="flex-items">
    <div class="abcd1">ABCD</div>
    <div class="date1">DATE</div>
</div>
```